# Trying to get or set sales tax country in Quickbooks SDK

Tags: quickbooks

I'm using Quickbooks SDK v11 to integrate with a C# application. Almost everything works fine, but I have a problem with the sales tax country. I want to add customer records to Quickbooks, and I can't figure out how to do it.

To see what's in Quickbooks already, I'm using the following code snippet:

```
ICustomerRet ret = [My code to retrieve a customer];
ENSalesTaxCountry stc = (ENSalesTaxCountry)ret.SalesTaxCountry.GetValue();
```

This works fine for a UK customer, but if the customer has a sales tax country of France, the GetValue() call throws an Exception.

A poke around with Intellisense reveals that my ENSalesTaxCountry type only has three options: stcAustralia, stcCanada and stcUK - clearly excluding France.

It seems that the SDK enum supports only these three countries, while Quickbooks itself supports a whole bunch of others.

Any ideas for how to patch the SDK or otherwise get round the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to rely on intellisense for documentation -  you can use the [IDN Onscreen Reference](https://member.developer.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html) for a complete description of SDK queries and responses. You are obviously either using the Canadian or UK edition of QuickBooks, so be sure to check *Allow CA or UK 2008+*, then either *CA* or *UK* to indicate the edition you are using.

However, once you do this you will see that the only sales tax countries supported by the SDK are the Australia, the UK and Canada. In order to find out whether qbXML is returning France or other values that are undocumented, you can call the `ToXmlString()` method on you ICustomerRet interface. This will give you the raw qbXML. If the value "France" is there, you should be able to see it.

If you find that the qbXML is supporting undocumented countries, you can try including them in customer add requests, but you have to build the qbXML yourself and use the request processor component instead of QBFC to send the message.

You might be able to get more information about this by posting on in the Intuit Developer forums, where you will find dedicated forums for both [UK](https://idnforums.intuit.com/categories.aspx?catid=67) and [Canadian](https://idnforums.intuit.com/categories.aspx?catid=15) QuickBooks development. In fact there is [an active discussion on sales tax countries](https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=67&threadid=17970) in the UK forum right now, but you won't find it to be encouraging.

Comment: Thanks for this. In fact, it's virtually a hiding to nothing since Intuit don't even support all of the countries I need (several EU countries, in which I have customers) are missing.